# powershell if statement for null condition

Tags: json, powershell

Please excuse this seemingly simple question for I know very little about powershell and just need it for a very small task.

I have a json config file called optionsConfig.json. The keys are possible environment variables and if the key is present when the script runs, the elements of the list that are associated with the key will also be assumed to be environment variables. 
The issue lies with the possibility that one or more of the elements in the list may not exist so the value would be null ( the logic for that is down below). I figure an if/else statement could catch that and delete the value from the list but I am not sure how to do this. Could anyone be of assistance?

Here is optionsConfig.json

```
{"test1": ["options_size", "options_connection", "options_object"],
 "test2":["options_customArgs", "options_noUDP", "options_noName"]}
```

The purpose of the $Options variable in the code below is to take each element in the list value for the respective test and assume that those elements are environment variables in the system, then find their values and form a dictionary object that will be used in the json.

Here is what I have so far.

```
# Read the JSON file into a custom object.
$configObj = Get-Content -Raw optionsConfig.json | ConvertFrom-Json

# Retrieve the environment variables whose
# names are listed in the $env:test property
# as name-value pairs.
Get-Item -Path env:* -Include $configObj.$env:test

$Options = Get-Item -Path env:* -Include $configObj.$env:test |
  % {$hash = @{}} {$hash[$_.Name]=$_.Value} {$hash}
$jObj = @{test= $env:test
      RECORD= $env:Record
      HASH= $Env:hash
      target= $env:Target
      options=$Options
     }

$jObj | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content "C:\Test\jsonStuff.json"
```

My final Json object in the new json file `jsonStuff.json` looks like this

```
{
    "options_size":  "default",
    "options_object":  "obj1",
    "options_connection":  "connected"
}
```

Unfortunately, it may look like this if one of the environment variables doesn't exist.

```
{
    "options_size":  "default",
    "options_object":  null,
    "options_connection":  "connected"
}
```

Is there any way I can delete they key from this newly formed Json object or not even add it to the json object based on whether the value is null? Thank you for bearing with my nonexistent powershell knowledge

[EDIT] Thank you all for the help. However, the updated code is not working. I'm not quite certain what the reason is. The code,

```
# Read the JSON file into a custom object.
$configObj = Get-Content -Raw C:\TestWare\security_test\optionsConfig.json | ConvertFrom-Json

# Retrieve the environment variables whose
# names are listed in the $env:tool property
# as name-value pairs.
Get-Item -Path env:* -Include $configObj.$env:test

$Options = Get-Item -Path env:* -Include $configObj.$env:test |
  % {$hash = @{}} {$hash[$_.Name]=$_.Value} {$hash} 

$Options | ForEach-Object {
    $NonEmptyProperties = $_.psobject.Properties | Where-Object {$null -ne $_.Value} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

    $_ | Select-Object -Property $NonEmptyProperties | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
    }

$jObj = @{test= $env:test
          Record= $env:Record
          HASH= $Env:hash
          target= $env:Target
          options=$Options
         }

$jObj | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content "C:\Test\jsonStuff.json"
```

runs as intended and populates the json file when it's in its own powershell file. It produces this additional output when ran in a powershell window too,

```
{"IsReadOnly":false,"IsFixedSize":false,"IsSynchronized":false,"Keys": 
["options_size","options_object","options_connection"],"Values":["default","obj1","connnected"],"SyncRoot":{},"Count":4}
```

I have placed the same exact code in another slightly larger powershell file that accomplishes a few other things that I think wouldn't affect this code and the code shows `options = System.Collections.Hashtable`. I'm aware that this pretty much means that there is some sort of dict or map there but I am not sure why it would properly produce a json obj in one file and not the other. Did I not specify my value correctly in the ForEach-Object loop?

Comment: try something like `if ($value -eq $null) { do something here }`

Comment: also `if(!$value)` / `if($value)`

Comment: Always put `$null` on the left side of the comparison.  Comparison operators are tricky when working with collections and act as filters. @NoRefundsNoReturns

Comment: example?  Or link?

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns here's an example: `1, $null, 3 -ne $null`

Comment: This ultimately does sound like a duplicate of the question that @robdy links to, so I'm closing this, but do let us know if it isn't and why.

Comment: @mklement0 sorry to bother, but could you please provide some insight to my recent edit and a possible reason for Systems.Collections.Hashtable being appended to my json obj instead of the expected dict?

Comment: @UCProgrammer: Please roll back your edit and use its content to ask a _new_, focused question; please try to get as close to an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as you can.

Comment: @mklement0 nevermind. I fixed it. Just needed to add "| ConvertTo-Json -Compress" to $Options. I still find it odd that I have to convert to json twice though

Comment: @UCProgrammer: If there's behavior that doesn't make sense to you, I encourage you to ask a new question nonetheless.